# Not in clause not working in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This query is not returning any records:

```
select abc from table1
where SOEID='A'
and ID in (
  select ID from Table2
  where column1='1234'
  and ID2 in (
    select ID2 from Table3
    where column2='5678'
  )
)
and reject_id not in (
  select reject_ID from error_table
);
```

But this query does return records:

```
select abc from table1
where SOEID='A'
and ID in (
  select ID from Table2 
  where column1='1234'
  and ID2 in (
    select ID2 from Table3
    where column2='5678'
  )
)
and reject_id not in (
  select reject_ID from error_table  where SOEID='A'
);
```

So I thought because I used a filter it is returning the records ie these records are not present in that particular SOEID's.

So I checked

```
select * from error_table
where reject_ID ='one record which was returned in the previous query';
```

This too is returning no records! What am I doing wrong here?

I thought because I used filter the query returned the records,
so I checked records without using the filter it is not returning any.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NOT IN` with subqueries.  It doesn't have the semantics that you expect.  If *any* value in the subquery returns a `NULL` value, then *no* rows are returned at all.  Usually, you just want to ignore `NULL` values.

So, use `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
Select abc
from  table1 t1
where SOEID = 'A' and
      ID in (select ID
             from  Table2 
             where column1 = '1234' and
                   ID2 in (select ID2 from Table3 where column2 = '5678')
            ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from error_table et
                  where t1.reject_id = et.reject_ID and
                        **SOEID='A'**
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies , I ll try this out :)

Comment: @varunrao besides, NOT IN clause mostly yields performance loss for queries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part:

```
and ID in (select ID from  Table2 
where column1='1234' and ID2 in (select ID2 from Table3 where column2='5678'))
```

change it to:

```
and ID in (select ID from  Table2 
where column1='1234') and ID2 in (select ID2 from Table3 where column2='5678')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but ID2 is a part of table 2

Comment: I used your code and did not change anything. The part I am highlighting is the IN (SELECT ... AND SELECT ...) that's the part that you cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that query

```
select reject_ID from error_table where SOEID='A'
```

returns no rows, while this one

```
select reject_ID from error_table
```

returns (or at least the first returns less than the second). So the first of your queries returns no rows, because all of them excluded by condition `and reject_id not in (<a lot if IDs>)`. The second query filters rows with condition `and reject_id not in (<no rows>)` - so no rows excluded.